# Pass the jquery data into php page without losing any special characters or plus sign

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

Morpho.SmartChip,SCPL.WIN.001,1.0.10,c585b0dc-70d2-4c93-be40-3e1d497a4d1e,MSO1300E2L0SW,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,HZNwrQn15hp3eA2HGYmtapVy1KdD6HyfxyA2sVhSpoX3VDoIt5OL8fueIL9gUlvTn6+qVAwKxJbeCvr+QAD4bhXviM8ksRwVMAUfFwh20aQFkzEd7ghVItGUtfei8Z2u2kA3i2sm0Q+qi3DlBSR1+/zpG1lDssn+JleDdSjY0UQr/C4eVMii0Rpamvqv48sT8TQ0GXZopR1ibqIkkgCgiwHCkQ7cYP+5RWooCd2tNyvpar1PI9DkK4V1dUNgRFTNhf31/UK+tAK9Bd343M3ZqkaufYOjrwYCL+vfLJc5xcufpGlqIEfNXtvD/pypZ1GD27CWriEBXyvWC84iTPspcA==

I am sending this comma seperated values generated in javascript code to php using this ajax code,

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : 'BioXml.php',
data : "capturedData="+mydata,
async: true,
success : function(response) {
alert(response);
}
});
```

But the data I am receiving on php page doesn't have any plus sign. And to overcome this problem I tried using encodeURIComponent but then it is replacing /,+ all these signs with %2C.

Comment: After you encoded in javascript, did you add a decode to the PHP?

Comment: @NigelRen — PHP will decode this data format automatically. Adding a manual decode will cause only problems.

Comment: You should use base64url (the URL safe variant of base64), not plain base64.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data which is vaguely application/x-www-form-urlencoded to the server and (implicitly because that is what jQuery does) setting a Content-Type header that says it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

In that encoding there are a number of characters that have special meaning (e.g. `+` means "space"). This is where being only *vaguely* in that format is causing you problems.

You need to encode them. You *can* use `encodeURIComponent` but doing this manually is pointless. jQuery will encode data for you if you pass an object instead of a string.

```
data: { "capturedData": mydata },
```

You claim:

> I tried using encodeURIComponent but then it is replacing /,+ all these signs with %2C.

It isn't clear why this is a problem. That's the whole point of encoding the data.

`+` means "a space" so you need some other way to express "a plus sign" and that way is `%2B` (with `%2C` being a comma).

When you read the data on the server, presumably (since you have `.php` in your URL) using `$_POST['capturedData']`, then PHP will have parsed the application/x-www-form-urlencoded data and put the original characters in the `$_POST` superglobal.